# Retrive a PDF from running a report with JasperReports Server API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, jasperserver

I am trying to run a report with the API provided by Jasper and get back a PDF. I am using C#. Their documentation say that it will be attached to the response but is not clear as to how one would go about getting the file or where really the response is. I apologize if this question is not terribly well informed and I am just missing something but I just started looking at this today. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/541220/run-report-jasperserver-rest-web-services
http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/docs/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide.pdf

And more specifically:

[Get report from jasperserver using REST webservice and asp.net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623685/get-report-from-jasperserver-using-rest-webservice-and-asp-net-c-sharp/9633661#9633661)

Answer (score 0):

You can run e report and get back it in different ways.

If you use HTTP API you just need to link to the report you want and provide username and password, instead you can use webservice and in that way you will have the report attached to the http response.

Hope this could help you!