# Jasper Reports on Azure cloud service

Tags: azure, jasper-reports

I am migrating an existing asp.net application to run as a web role in an azure cloud service and SQL Azure database ,I have a problem in reports as I am using Jasper reports .

any suggestion how can I run jasper reports on azure cloud service ?

Answer (score 0):

Jasper on ASP.NET is not officially supported. You can try your luck by having Jasper Reporting Server in you Azure Project and installation, setup as a part of your startup OR install Reporting Server in Azure VM consume the same in ASP.NET as REST API to Jasper Server [Get report from jasperserver using REST webservice and asp.net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623685/get-report-from-jasperserver-using-rest-webservice-and-asp-net-c-sharp)