# run jasper report using rest request in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, report, jasperserver

I have been trying for days to get jasper reports integrated with my .net website.  I have tried several ways including the soap and rest service as well as a custom library suggested in another post(http://freeze.ro/?q=node/7).  I know I am close but I am fairly new to this and am still trying to understand how it all works.  Most people suggest using the rest method and I found a good example on here but I am still getting an error Bad Request.  This is my code for the rest request.

```
             WebClient httpClient = new WebClient();
        httpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        httpClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        // Build resourceDescriptor
        string requestXml;
        requestXml = "<resourceDescriptor name=\"Invoice\" wsType=\"reportUnit\" uriString=\"/reports/Nosreports/Invoice\"";
        requestXml += " isNew=\"false\">";

        requestXml += "   <parameter name=\"invoiceid\">1016242</parameter>n";
        requestXml += "</resourceDescriptor>";

        // Send PUT, the requestAllResult contains the above <report>...

        string requestAllResult = httpClient.UploadString("http://SRV9:8080/jasperserver/rest/report/reports/NOSreports/Invoice?RUN_OUTPUT_FORMAT=PDF", "PUT", requestXml);


        // Extract uuid and file
        System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(requestAllResult);
        XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("uuid");
        string uuid = node.InnerText;

        //Build GET URL
        string reportUrl = "http://SRV9:8080/jasperserver/rest/resources/report/";
        reportUrl += uuid;
        reportUrl += "?file=report";

        // Get report
        string report;
        report = httpClient.DownloadString(reportUrl);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated I have read and read and am ready to give up, I just hate to try and switch to a new reporting service at this point in my project.

Comment: this really helped me a lot, hope it helps u too 

[same problem solved][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623685/get-report-from-jasperserver-using-rest-webservice-and-asp-net-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ovan that definitely would have helped me. Unfortunately we have switched to Crystal Reports so I no longer need this.

If anyone has this problem check this link posted by Ovan.

[Get report from jasperserver using REST webservice and asp.net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623685/get-report-from-jasperserver-using-rest-webservice-and-asp-net-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I success calling Jasper report via rest v2.
Please see my script as attached URL.
Hope it is helpful for you.

[Asp.net MVC call Jasper report via REST v2 service](http://nagagechou.blogspot.tw/2016/12/call-jasper-rest-v2-with-aspnet-mvc.html)